# Full page 3 column layout in DomPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to generate pdf like this:

```
public function generatePdf($customerId){
    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

    $dompdf->setOptions($options);
    $dompdf->loadHtml($this->renderHtml());

    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potrait');

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();
    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream();
}
```

the `$this->renderHtml()` will return string containing html text like this:

```
       <style>
        .first-page .bottom{
          display:inline;
          width:100%;
        }
        .first-page .bottom .section{
          display: block;
          width:25%;
          height: 30px;
        }
        .first-page .bottom .left.section{
        }
        .first-page .bottom .right.section{
          width:37%;
          margin-right:0;
        }
      </style>
      <div class = "first-page">
        <div class = "bottom">
           <div class="left section">
              <p class="title">How to activate Card</p>
              <p class="main">
                <ol>
                   <li>Open Purse Pay</li>
                   <li>Lo-in to V-Card feature</li>
                   <li>Input your V-Card number.</li>
                </ol>
              </p>
           </div>
           <div class="middle section">
              <p class="title">How to use V-Card</p>
              <p class="main">
                <ol>
                   <li>Find merchant who accept V-Card payment</li>
                   <li>Stick QR-Code to Merchant Machine ‘<i>White Box</i>’ Purse Pay.</li>
                   <li>Check your transaction and credit amount from Purse Pay APP.</li>
                </ol>
              </p>
           </div>
           <div class="right section">
              <p class="title">Tips to use V-card safely</p>
              <p class="main">
                <ol>
                   <li>If you lost yout card, block your card immediately from Purse Pay App or you can contact our Customer Support <span class="bold">150 555</span>.</li>
                   <li>Keep your pin secret</li>
                   <li>Always update if you have changes on your data (Phone number, e-mail, shipping address, profile picture, etc)</li>
                   <li>If you do not use your card anymore, please shred or cut your V-Card into pieces using magenetic shredder.</li>
                   <li>Jika kartu sudah tidak lagi digunakan, harap untuk menggunting kartu V-card dengan gunting magnetik.</li>
                </ol>
              </p>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

the result will looks like this in pdf, the div is overlapping and all the content is aligning to the left:

[image: example]

i want the result to have 3 column distributed evenly like this :

[image: example]

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, you need to test your css, it's missing many things to make it works.
See the code bellow : 
https://jsfiddle.net/0L25vxo8/2/

```
.first-page .bottom{
  display:inline;
  width:100%;
}
.first-page .bottom .section{
  display: block;
  width:32%; /* And a width for all section */
  float: left; /* Adding a floating attribute */
  height: 30px;
}
.first-page .bottom .left.section{

}
.first-page .bottom .right.section{
  width:33%; /* Overide width */
}
.first-page .bottom .middle.section{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on DOMPDF Version ^1.2

HTML:

```
<div class="header-container container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            Test Left
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            Test Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And SCSS:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

For reference, DOMPDF has the following flags set:

```
$options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use flex grid to do that.

```
div.bottom{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

div.section {
     flex:1
}
```

This way every section will have same width, about 33%. Try this removing all previous styles setup. Hope it helps.

Comment: dompdf doesn't support flex